# Target Users with Commands

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command where it will check for the user(s) mentioned and saving that to an array, so I can use a method on it, etc.

*For example*, giving someone a role.

---

Save the the user(s) mentioned in a message (`message.mentions.users`) to an array
Give the user(s) mentioned a specified role (or some other method)

---

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you trying to concatenate the `message.mentions.users` array with another array?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to copy an arrays to another array.
I want to use the keys in the 'message.mentions.users' array (the users mentioned) and give them a role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check for the user(s) mentioned and saving that to an array

That's not needed. `message.mentions.users` is already an array, you could still save it by creating another variable if you want, but for giving them a role, you only need to execute a command **for each** one of them.

To do this we're going to use the `.forEach()` method:

```
var userlist = message.mentions.users; // Saving userlist to a variable
userlist.forEach(function(user){
    console.log(user); // This should log every mentioned user
});
```

This way you could easily execute a command for each one of them.

But for giving them a role, you would have to use the Back-End API (HTTP Requests)

> PUT/DELETE /api/guilds/{guildId}/members/{userId}/roles/{roleId} [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://github.com/hammerandchisel/discord-api-docs/issues/130)

HTTP Requests can be done with jQuery's ajax:
(Remembering all discord requests Base URL should be https://discordapp.com/api):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/guilds/{guildId}/members/{userId}/roles/{roleId}',
    type: 'PUT', // Or delete
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

You would only need to transform `message.mentions.users` to their ID, which you could easily do this using the `.forEach()` loop.

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
var userlist = message.mentions.users; // Saving userlist to a variable
userlist.forEach(function(user){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/guilds/' + message.guild.id + '/members/' + user + '/roles/{roleId}', // In this case the ID of the role
        type: 'PUT', // Or delete
        success: function(result) {
            // Do something with the result
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: If `user[Object(user)[0]]` would get the key for the users ID from the object, how would I interact with it like you could with `message.author.[method]` or `message.member.[method]`? Or do I need jQuery? I never used jQuery or ajax, and I'm pretty new with JavaScript, so idk. \*shrug\*

Comment: No... you're getting it wrong. `forEach` just iterate the array. The `user` from the variable in the `forEach` loop above, should execute **each** user, so if you use: `console.log(user[Object(user[0])])` as you mentioned, it should print everyone's ID. The jQuery's ajax is just for giving them a role. If you are not acquainted with HTTP requests, I suggest you learn it as soon as possible. They are going to make requests to the Discord API, or any other Back-End API you need.

Comment: Alright, I looked up jQuery and HTTP requests and such. So I would need that if I wanted to ban/kick someone?

Comment: Yes, but all of this is by using the pure Discord API, you could still use other APIs if you want, they'll do the same thing. For example, [hydrabolt](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/)'s API.

Comment: Using it should reduce your code (Since all HTTP requests are inside the API already), so you won't need ajax anymore, but you'll still need the `forEach` loop. [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) is the hydrabolt API's doc if you need it.

Comment: For {guildID}, {userID}, and {roleID}, I can use variables, right?

Comment: Yes. You should get them by enabling Discord DEV Mode or with its own api

Comment: Yes, but not like this, something more like: `url: '/api/guilds/' + message.guild.id + '/members/' + user + '/roles/{roleId}'` (`user` should be replaced to the user id when inside the forEach loop.

Comment: While it's inside the `forEach` loop? Can you give me an example?